# Cypress click element within parent

Tags: typescript, cypress

All black boxes and red boxes are the same,
I would like to click on a black that is in the same box as green box,
how should I form cypress code to do it?

I tried

cy.contains('green box').parent().get('black box').click()

cy.contains('green box').parent().find('black box').click()

[image: click here, look at this image example]

Comment: Post your relevant html markup instead of image.

Answer (score 4):

There is also the filtering approach

- get all the red boxes
- apply a filter to select the one with "green box"
- find it's "black box" child

```js
cy.contains('red box')    
  .filter(':contains("green box")')
  .find(':contains("black box")').click()
```

Please note, if you use `.find('black box')` as in your example it's going to look for a tag `<black box>` not the text "black box" as in `<span>black box</span>`.

You would need to figure out the selectors needed for each part of the query.

- `contains()` use selectors for text content
- `find()` uses tags like `<div>`, `<span>`
- `:contains(...)` modifies the `find()` selector to behave more like `contains()`

So the example you gave could be

```js
cy.contains('green box')
  .parents(':contains("red box")')
  .find(':contains("black box")').click()
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case of your first command, the `.parent().get('black box')` is breaking the chain, because `.get()` always start off at the root element - so the commands before don't affect it.

In the case of your second command, use `.parents()` instead of `.parent()` and Cypress is smart enough to perform the `.find()` off all the parents it finds,

```js
cy.contains('green box').parents().find('black box').click()
```

There are some really good examples of traversal command use here [Cypress examples (v13.3.1)](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/commands/traversal.html#parents).

You can also specify the red box directly using `contains(selector, text)`

```js
cy.contains(':contains("red box")', 'green box').find('black box').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the exact HTML, some of this contains assumptions but:

You'll want to use `cy.find()`. `cy.get()` starts searching for elements at the root, where `cy.find()` (or `cy.within()`) searches from the previously yielded element(s).

Additionally, `cy.parent()` only goes up one step in the DOM. So, if the parent element you want is more than one step up, Cypress will fail to find the element you want. [Instead, you can use `cy.parents()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/parents) to traverse up the DOM until the matching element is found.

Assuming an HTML structure like:

```
<div>
  <div class="red">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="black" />
      <div class="blue" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="red">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="black" />
      <div class="yellow" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="red">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="black" />
      <div class="green" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, to get the div with `.black` that also has a sibling of `.green`, your code would look something like:

```js
cy.get('.green')
  .parents('.red')
  .find('.black')
  .click();
```

If the `.green` and `.black` elements are true siblings, this can be [shorthanded with `cy.siblings()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/siblings)

```js
cy.get('.green')
  .siblings('.black')
  .click();
```